# HTML5 & CSS3 Using multiple Pseudo classes and translateX/Y properties

Tags: html, css, translate, pseudo-class

So first of all let me admit I'm not the best at coding, I'm a graphic designer but I 'm trying to teach myself HTML5. I have managed to troubleshoot most of my problemsbut I'm stumped now.

Essentially my problem is when you click a thumbnail within the iframe, it aligns the thumbnail at the very top of the screen. I tried adding translateY to the "page" class, and I also tried it inside the iframe pages but that caused the main picture to be misaligned.

My testpage is online at http://www.brodylahd.com/index2

In reply to Cat Chen

yes i think that is what i need to do... but will it still have the same horizontal movement?

Comment: Do you mean you want to scroll the page within the iframe in order to align the current interacting album with the top of the iframe?

Comment: I just don't want the "page" div to move vertically at all when the thumbnail is pressed

Comment: So the iframe should focus to the current page?

Comment: I've merged your cookie based accounts, you can now leave comments under answers and edit your question. Please consider associating an OpenID with your account to avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnail links aligning the it's container at the very top of the screen on click because you are using anchors ([Uri Fragments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) like #a1 #a2 #a3 in href attributes.

You can try to remove that fragments or prevent in-page movement using a small javascript workaround like this:

```
$('#thumbs').find('a').bind('click', function() {
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with going to anchors in `iframe`, so that browsers tend to center on the content in them if you're targeting them.

The simplest solution in your case (but not ideal) is to control where the scroll would be, so if you'll add

```
#a1 { position:relative; top: -186px; }
#wrapper { position:relative; top: 186px; }
```

The page would be centered more visually correct, but still would scroll.

If you want to still use CSS, you can try to change your links+`#aN:target .page{…}` behavior to a one, that would use labels and radio-buttons that would go before `.page` blocks: `#aN:checked+.page{…}`, but I'm not sure if browsers would or wouldn't scroll the page when you're using radios instead of links.